# Best practice for showing UI error messages based on ViewModel state

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, localization

I have a WPF application in which I want to show "friendly" and verbose error descriptions if the ViewModel state indicates that an error occurred. So, as a very simple first pass I have:

#### XAML

```
<Label>
  <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding Path=ErrorMessage}" />
</Label>
```

#### ViewModel

```
public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

private void DoSomething()
{
    try { /* ... */ }
    catch (Exception1) { ErrorMessage = "Long description 1"; }
    catch (Exception2) { ErrorMessage = "Long description 2"; }
    catch (Exception3) { ErrorMessage = "Long description 3"; }
}
```

(Note, `PropertyChanged.Fody` is used to automatically implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the ViewModel property above, and `DoSomething()` is triggered via a `RelayCommand`.)

---

This works just fine, but of course I don't want those long description strings in the ViewModel code. So I started to read up on WPF localization, `ResourceDictionary` and so on, and I very quickly got completely lost.

It seems to me that it would be really ideal if I could do something like this:

#### XAML (Hypothetical)

```
<Label>
  <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding Path=Error, Converter?=???}" />
</Label>
```

#### ViewModel (Hypothetical)

```
public enum Errors { None, Error1, Error2, Error3 };
public Errors Error get; set; }

private void DoSomething()
{
    try { /* ... */ }
    catch (Exception1) { Error = Errors.Error1; }
    catch (Exception2) { Error = Errors.Error2; }
    catch (Exception3) { Error = Errors.Error3; }
}
```

#### Somewhere? (Totally hypothetical)

```
<Strings>
    <String Key="MyViewModel.Errors.Error1">
        Long description 1
    </String>
    <!-- etc. -->
</Strings>
```

---

Now, the above is totally imaginary, and from what I've read I'm thinking that a `ResourceDictionary` *might* be the place to store the strings. But I can't figure out how to associate the strings with an enumeration of possible error conditions. Of course it doesn't have to be an `enum` either -- I could store a string key or something in the `Error` field -- that's just what seemed most ideal to me.

I know that I could put string resources in a `ResourceDictionary` and then use `Application.Current.Resources` in the ViewModel code to look up the strings and use that to populate `ErrorMessage`. But I think that would be bad - the ViewModel shouldn't know or care about the actual message text, that's a View concern. So it seems to me that the View should figure out the appropriate string to render based on the ViewModel state.

Ideally the string should also be localizable in the future, although I'm not currently localizing the application (I don't yet know enough about WPF localization and it's not required for this app).

**The question is, can you point me in the right direction regarding WPF best practices for showing keyed messages like in the above examples?** I do not mind doing the legwork to learn what I need to learn, but I quickly got totally lost and confused when reading about this online and just need a little guidance. Thank you!

Comment: Go down the error code route and use the value converter in the view to lookup the localized error message based on some culture key.

Comment: You haven't considered INotifyDataErrorInfo and IDataErrorInfo?

Comment: @Will No, I haven't (maybe I should have clarified in the post that I'm very new to WPF and there's a lot about it I don't know yet). Would you care to elaborate on your suggestion and turn it into an Answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly fine and very common for a view model to expose string values that the view binds to using TextBlock elements. If you don't want to hardcode the string values into the view model class you could store the strings in a separate class:

**View Model:**

```
private void DoSomething()
{
    try { /* ... */ }
    catch (Exception1) { ErrorMessage = StringResources.ErrorMessageA; }
    catch (Exception2) { ErrorMessage = StringResources.ErrorMessageB; }
}
```

**StringResources.cs:**

```
public static class StringResources
{
    public const string ErrorMessageA = "...";
    public const string ErrorMessagB = "...";
}
```

If you don't like this for some reason you could still expose keys such as "Error1" and "Error2" from the view model and then use a converter or a custom markup extension to translate these to actual string values in the view. Please refer to the following links for more information:

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/35159/wpf-localization-using-resx-files

https://wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html

[Recommendation on a XAML RESX markup extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591421/recommendation-on-a-xaml-resx-markup-extension)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided examples, this is an alternative:

You *could* (there are a **lot** of ways to do this), use a `Style` on your `TextBlock` and set its `Text` according to the error on your `ViewModel`, like this:

#### enum:

```
public enum Error
{
    None,
    Error1,
    Error2,
    Error3
}
```

(None is not a keyword in C#)

#### View Model:

```
public Error CurrentError { get; set; }
```

#### XAML example

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentError}" Value="{x:Static local:Error.None}">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="No error" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentError}" Value="{x:Static local:Error.Error1}">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Long description 1" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentError}" Value="{x:Static local:Error.Error2}">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Long description 2" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentError}" Value="{x:Static local:Error.Error3}">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Long description 3" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

**PS:** If the `enum` is not on the same `namespace` as the `Window`/`Page`/whatever (and it probably shouldn't), you'll have to replace "`local:`" with the appropriate namespace.

---

This way you can basically do everything with the `TextBlock` (like change its `Visibility` when there are no errors, change its `Foreground`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks... this would definitely work, but it feels wrong to me to use _styles_ to accomplish this. For one thing it pollutes the XAML where the label is, and for another if I end up with several such labels on different pages (with different sets of error codes) it results in a lot of redundant boilerplate code.